# jquery slider not working in visual composer custom shortcode in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

[image]

[image]

I am trying to make custom short code in visual composer ,ever thing was fine when i am applying text,heading,single images,but now I have requirement of create custom short code with slider bar, my jQuery can't working with slider bar. jQuery is included I have checked that, but the images are not displaying as slider, it display as single images.I wrote my "div" in for each loop is it correct?

My code for images is

```
foreach($image_ids as $image_id)
{
    $images = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'company_logo');

    $html.= '<div id="slideshow"><a href="#" class="slideshow-prev">&laquo;</a><ul><li>';
    $html.='<img src="'.$images[0].'" alt="'.$atts['title'].'">';
    $html.= '</li></ul><a href="#" class="slideshow-next">&raquo;</a></div>';

    $images++;
}
```

The jQuery code is:

```
//an image width in pixels 
var imageWidth = 600;

//DOM and all content is loaded 
$(window).ready(function () {

    var currentImage = 0;

    //set image count 
    var allImages = $('#slideshow li img').length;

    //setup slideshow frame width
    $('#slideshow ul').width(allImages * imageWidth);

    //attach click event to slideshow buttons
    $('.slideshow-next').click(function () {

        //increase image counter
        currentImage++;
        //if we are at the end let set it to 0
        if (currentImage >= allImages) currentImage = 0;
        //calcualte and set position
        setFramePosition(currentImage);

    });

    $('.slideshow-prev').click(function () {

        //decrease image counter
        currentImage--;
        //if we are at the end let set it to 0
        if (currentImage < 0) currentImage = allImages - 1;
        //calcualte and set position
        setFramePosition(currentImage);

    });

});

//calculate the slideshow frame position and animate it to the new position
function setFramePosition(pos) {

    //calculate position
    var px = imageWidth * pos * -1;
    //set ul left position
    $('#slideshow ul').animate({
        left: px
    }, 300);
}
```

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: In console it displays: "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at my.js?ver=1.0.0:6".

Comment: try my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your for loop is wrong . try this.

```
    $Inc = 0;

    foreach($image_ids as $image_id)
    {
        $images = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'company_logo');

        $html.= '<div id="slideshow"><a href="#" class="slideshow-prev">&laquo;</a><ul><li>';
        $html.='<img src="'.$images[$Inc].'" alt="'.$atts['title'].'">';
        $html.= '</li></ul><a href="#" class="slideshow-next">&raquo;</a></div>';

        $images++;
        $Inc++;
    }
```

and your js

```
    //an image width in pixels 
    var imageWidth = 600;


    //DOM and all content is loaded 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        var currentImage = 0;

        //set image count 
        var allImages = $('#slideshow li img').length;

        //setup slideshow frame width
        $('#slideshow ul').width(allImages * imageWidth);

        //attach click event to slideshow buttons
        $('.slideshow-next').click(function () {

            //increase image counter
            currentImage++;
            //if we are at the end let set it to 0
            if (currentImage >= allImages) currentImage = 0;
            //calcualte and set position
            setFramePosition(currentImage);

        });

        $('.slideshow-prev').click(function () {

            //decrease image counter
            currentImage--;
            //if we are at the end let set it to 0
            if (currentImage < 0) currentImage = allImages - 1;
            //calcualte and set position
            setFramePosition(currentImage);

        });

    });

    //calculate the slideshow frame position and animate it to the new position
    //calculate the slideshow frame position and animate it to the new position
    function setFramePosition(pos) {

        //calculate position
        var px = imageWidth * pos * -1;
        //set ul left position
        jQuery('#slideshow ul').animate({
            left: px
        }, 300);
    }
```

Comment: Thanx perfect works,slider starts now,but it display extra another 3 images arrow and spaces  something like this(photo is in question)

Comment: At top of question.

Comment: change this line `$html.='<img src="'.$images[0].'" alt="'.$atts['title'].'">';`

Comment: Just trying your code and result is at 1st no. photo at top of question.

Comment: Ok,i will try,thanx for sharing knowledge.